# Spring kafka consume records with some delay

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using spring kafka in my application. I want to add some delay of 15 mins for consuming the records for one of the listener - kafkaRetryListenerContainerFactory. I have two listeners. Below is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(primaryConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaRetryListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(retryConsumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(this.kafkaConfigProperties.getConsumerConcurrency());
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);       
    return factory;
}
```

Kafka retry listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.retry.topic}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer-group-id}", 
        containerFactory = "kafkaRetryListenerContainerFactory", id = "retry.id")
public void retryMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    Thread.sleep(900000);
    LOG.info(String.format("Consumed retry message -> %s", record.toString()));
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

When I added Thread.sleep(), I'm getting continuous rebalancing error in the logs

```
Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
```

My spring kafka version is 2.3.4

Below are the config values:

max.poll.interval.ms = 1200000 (this is higher than thread.sleep)

heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000

session.timeout.ms = 10000

I have tried ack.nack(900000); Still getting the rebalancing error

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter is not the right approach; you need to `Thread.sleep()` the thread and make sure that `max.poll.interval.ms` is larger than the total sleep and processing time for the records received by the poll.

In 2.3, the container has the option to sleep between polls; with earlier versions, you have to do the sleep yourself.

**EDIT**

I just found this in my `server.properties` (homebrew on Mac OS):

```
############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

That explains why we see the partitions initially assigned to the first consumer (see comment below).

Setting it back to the default 3000 works for me.

Comment: Ok. So what you are telling is that filtered records won't be consumed again

Comment: Correct; filtering is all about discarding records that you aren't interested in.

Comment: Turn on debug logging and post the log someplace (pastebin etc).

Comment: I have updated the question. I have two kafka container factories for two listeners. From the logs I can see the values are correctly set.

Comment: A rebalance should not occur with those settings (unless another instance is started). If you want to share a complete small project that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look.

Comment: Interesting point is that, if I comment out Thread.sleep rebalancing error goes out

Comment: I have put a sample project with these configs in github https://github.com/pvkrishnanunni/spring-kafka-demo. Please take a look. You have to give the kafka connection details in application.properties

Comment: Your concurrency is 6; what I observe is the first container is initially assigned all 6 partitions and starts consuming; then additional consumers come up, causing the rebalance. I was able to solve it by setting `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=10000` in the broker `server.properties`. (The default is supposed to be 3 seconds but the assignment seems to happen much faster than that). BTW I saw the same behavior regardless of whether the `sleep()` was present.

Comment: @GaryRussell, here we have tow containers but their consumers listening to different topic.  So  first container is initially assigned all 6 partitions and starts consuming as concurrency is 6. When additional 6 consumers come up, they are going to listen totally different topic and group. So I am confused why it is causing rebalancing

Comment: In the provided sample there are 2 listeners each with a concurrency of 6. The concurrent container fires up 6 child containers for each topic. The problem (cause by the 0 rebalance delay) is the first child container gets all 6 partitions; then as the other 5 containers are started a rebalance is initiated but the first container (consumer) is blocked on the sleep. Increasing the rebalance delay gives the broker time to wait for all 6 consumers to start before assigning partitions.